# Is there any limit in terms of number of characters in bs4.BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML document with over 1800 links.

I'm trying to parse href part of all these links.

```
for link in soup.body.find_all('a', attrs={'data-tag':'Homepage Library'}):
    if link.attrs["href"]:
        links.append(link.attrs["href"])

print len(links)
```

Even though there are over 1800 links in the original file, Beautiful Soup finds only 266.

The html is pretty big, so I was thinking maybe there is some limit in the number of characters accepted by bs4.BeautifulSoup ?

If not, then why it doesn't return all links?

I'm sure there is over 1800 links with attribute data-tag:"Homepage Library", because I checked this with shell script:

```
grep 'data-tag="Homepage Library"' > links.txt
```

Comment: Are there non-anchor tags that have the data-tag="Homepage Library" attribute?

Comment: No, only anchor tags have this attribute.

Comment: @user2758414 could you share the link to the page you are using?

Comment: https://pl.khanacademy.org/